# Excel Count Function to Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to count all rows with a value but not duplicate. So in my picture I need to get 19 total units. If column B has a value and column C and so on, I only want to count that once.

Not sure I make sense. I need to count each row once if there is a value in at least one of the columns.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One can use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((B2:B31<>"")+(C2:C31<>"")+(D2:D31<>"")>0))
```

Or MMULT():

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(--(B2:D31<>""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:D31)^0))>0))
```

This second one may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode on some versions.

[image]

Comment: When I use the sumproduct I get 30, I need 19.

Comment: Scott Sir, perfect !!

Comment: @GamingNerd83 see edit.  That is what I get for just typing the formulas.

Comment: What if 0 is entered as an amount?

Comment: @ForwardEd I am looking for any cell that is not and empty string.  So no matter what the OP uses as the marker it should pick it up.

Comment: I was just wondering if someone were to actually enter 0 would the OP want it counted as 1 since its matching, or would they prefer 0's not to be counted.  So not really a Q for you per say Scott, but good to know how the formula treats that POTENTIALLY special case.